# MySQL dependencies conflicts

Tags: linux, rpm, mysql

I have installed Cloudera Server and Agent successfully, but I am facing issues installing MySQL.

I have setup a local repository for this installation as I require offline installation.

How do I resolve the conflicts for offline installation? I am able to install mysql successfully, if I am connected to the Internet.

```
[root@localhost repo]# yum install mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.16-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.16-1.el6 for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.16-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.16-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: net-tools for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.16-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.7.16-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-libs(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 for package: mysql-community-client-5.7.16-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.7.16-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package net-tools.x86_64 0:2.0-0.17.20131004git.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: MySQL-python-1.2.3-11.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package: MySQL-python-1.2.3-11.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.7.16-1.el6 will be obsoleting
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: MySQL-python-1.2.3-11.el7.x86_64 (@cloudera-manager)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Removing: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.16-1.el6.x86_64 (cloudera-manager)
               Not found
Error: Package: MySQL-python-1.2.3-11.el7.x86_64 (@cloudera-manager)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Removing: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.16-1.el6.x86_64 (cloudera-manager)
              ~libmysqlclient.so.20()(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Removing: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.16-1.el6.x86_64 (cloudera-manager)
               Not found
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Removing: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.16-1.el6.x86_64 (cloudera-manager)
              ~libmysqlclient.so.20()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem when raising an AWS RHEL Instance.

MariaDB is installed by deualt and it causes some conflicts.
If you only want to use MySQL, just remove MariaDB by:

```
sudo yum remove mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Comment: Hey @youcanlearnanything , How did you resolve the MySQL dependencies when working offline? (Libraries such as libaio, perl etc..)